# Android - Making a listview row invisible

Tags: android, listview, row

I am attempting to make a list view row empty if it has no text. I have achieved this before, but I'm not sure how I did it. At the moment, I have managed to get it to not show anything when the text is equal to nothing, however it still shows the row border.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, MainActivity.values) {
              @Override
              public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);


                text1.setText(MainActivity.values[position]);
                text2.setText(MainActivity.numvalues[position]);

                    if (MainActivity.values[position].equals("")) {
                        text1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        text1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        text2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else {
                        text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                return view;
              }
            };
```

Comment: Why do you set the visibility **twice**? `GONE` is enough. Save on CPU cycles!

Answer (score 1):

Before init ArrayAdapter remove from MainActivity.values and MainActivity.numvalues items that don't need to show.

Answer (score 1):

`VIEW.GONE` won't work as you want, i've tried it, but there is one thing you can do to avoid this problem at all, maybe you should remove all of your empty rows **before you past your items into adapter?**